# How works a type conversion in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some trouble with types in my test angular app. I wrote rest service with follow method:

```
@PutMapping("/notes")
    public Note updateNote(@RequestBody Note note) {
        System.out.println("It works");
        return service.updateNote(note);
    }
```

I wrote angular service:

```
updateNote(note: Note): Observable<any> {
    console.log("Service Updatenote " + typeof note);
    return this.http.put(this.serverURL, note, httpOptions);
  }
```

I wrote angular component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NotesDataService} from '../../services/notes-data.service';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Note} from '../../models/note';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-note',
  templateUrl: './update-note.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-note.component.css']
})
export class UpdateNoteComponent implements OnInit {

  // notedata: FormGroup;
  // noteId;
  currentNote: Note;
  submited: boolean = false;

  constructor(private dataservise: NotesDataService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const noteId = +this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.dataservise.getNoteById(noteId).subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Data ng init " + data);
      this.currentNote = data });
  }

  onClickSubmit() {
    console.log(this.currentNote);
    this.dataservise.updateNote(this.currentNote);
  }
}
```

And wrote the form:

```
<div [hidden]="submited">
<form #noteUpdateForm (ngSubmit)="onClickSubmit()">
  <div class="formGroup">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" required
           [(ngModel)]="currentNote.title" name="title" #title="ngModel">
    <div [hidden]="title.valid || title.pristine"
         class="alert alert-danger">
      Title is required
    </div>
  </div>
  <label for="body">Body</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="body" required
         [(ngModel)]="currentNote.body" name="body" #body="ngModel">
  <div [hidden]="body.valid || body.pristine"
       class="alert alert-danger">
    Body is required
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Please, tell me why it does not works? Where type of "currentNote" changes to Object or where I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are you doing? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? It would be much easier for us to explain the problem if we knew what the problem is in the first place.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: It have to change data on java rest service. At first it get data from a server with data for current Note object. Then I change the object fields in the form and try to send the changed Note to rest server, but it don't send it. I think it can happen because of currentNote change own type somewhere, but can't understand where it happens and how cast Object to Note. Sorry for my excellent English)

Comment: @Adrita Sharma, UpdateNoteComponent.html:5 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (UpdateNoteComponent.html:6)
   ...
UpdateNoteComponent.html:5 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 11, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}

Comment: The request is never sent because you never subscribe() to the observable returned by updateNote().

Comment: And you get that error because you're trying to access the note of the component from the view before the note has been received from the server (and the currentNode is thus `undefined`, as the error tells). Surround your view by a `<div *ngIf="currentNote">`

Comment: @JB Nizet, It start works!=) I so long time spend to find this mistake... Thank you so much for your help!)